# Tool for drawing Smartphones from different 3D Perspectives

Tags: vector, 3d, tools, perspective, data-visualisation

For presentation purposes, I need to visualize a process that involves rotating the smartphone in 3D-space. Hence, I am looking for a drawing tool (or a way), which has smartphone graphics (preferably generic) that can be individually rotated around all 3 axis.

Comment: So you need to be able to draw on the smartphone and rotate it in 3D? Do you need to rotate it in real time?

Comment: So your asking for a software recommendation for a 3d app? Im not sure that is in scope. You can use any 3d capable app such as phothoshop, maya, max, modo, sketchup etc... or blender its free, heres a model for you http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/samsung-galaxy-s3-98700.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about SketchUp? I have found it easy to learn and use, and it is backed by a pretty big 3D model repository. You can export 2D graphics from it too.

**Sketchup:** http://www.sketchup.com/ (you can download the free Sketchup Make and try it out)

**Sketchup repository:** https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/index.html